# Sequence Convergence Implies Series Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $\{x_n\}$ is a monotone decreasing sequence with $nx_n\to0$.  Does it follow that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n<\infty$?

Comment: You may want to consider $$x_n = \frac{1}{n(\log(n+1))^{\alpha}} $$ with $\alpha >0$. Some choice will lead to convergence, while some other will lead to divergence.

Comment: Personal input?

Answer (score 2):

No. Take $x_{n}=\frac{1}{n\log n}$.